# How to insert a 2D array into an empty 3D array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm new to Java, and I'd like to know how I can insert a 2D array (with elements of course) into an empty 3D array using nested for loops in Java?

```java
String[][][] ProductAllData2 = new String[10][getPInputsWithParameter(getPInputs()).length][getPInputsWithParameter(getPInputs()).length];

String [][] receivedPInputsWithParameter = getPInputsWithParameter(getPInputs());
         
for(int i = 0; i < ProductAllData2.length; i++) { //Inserts in 3D array
            
    for(int j = 0; j < ProductAllData2[i].length; j++) {
        ProductAllData2[i][j] = new String[receivedPInputsWithParameter[j].length];
  
        for(int k = 0; k < ProductAllData2[i][j].length; k++) {
            ProductAllData2[i][j][k] = receivedPInputsWithParameter[j][k];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This is definetly possible, however, we need to see your sample input, expected output and the way you tried to insert a 2D array into an empty 3D one to help you with the solution (at least an attempt). Would you provide these? :)

Comment: okki, brb, I'll insert my code

Comment: By _inserting a 2D array_ you mean copying the contents of existing 2D array into new 3D array?

Comment: Yes yes, exactly

Comment: One more thing. Please, don't post images. The people here don't like rewritting your code to their IDE to help you out (it takes too much of time). Would you paste the formatted code instead? Don't forget the propert formatting. Thank you.

Comment: ohh ok ok, sorry My bad, really new here

Comment: Your code successfully copies the contents of 2D array to all elements of the 3D array.  Can you describe the problem/error/unexpected behavior that you get?

Comment: @RalphHenry: Not a problem :) I am glad you have edited your question.

Comment: @AlexRudenko, woops, I think I inserted my alternative 3d array which just gets the length of the 2d array:String[][][] ProductAllData2 = new String[10][getPInputsWithParameter(getPInputs()).length][getPInputsWithParameter(getPInputs()).length];




This  should be:  String[][][] ProductAllData2 = new String[10][10][8];  (since we were instructed to have limitations in our array.

what Im getting is this error:
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
 at prog2exer1.Products.firstTableMouseClicked(Products.java:505)

Comment: @AlexRudenko this is the line 505:        ProductAllData2[i][j] = new String[receivedPInputsWithParameter[j].length];

Comment: @AlexRudenko I have posted a more specific question about the issue

Answer (score 2):

In java 2D array is the array of arrays; therefore it's not mandatory for 2D array (row/col) to have each row with the same size.

The same for 3D array: this is an array of 2D arrays.

So to insert 2D array into 3D array, you just need to set 2D array into 1D array with 2D elements.

```
int[][][] dest = {
        // id = 0
        {
                { 1, 2, 3 },
                { 4, 5, 6 }
        },
        // id = 1
        {
                { 7, 8, 9 },
                { 10, 11, 12 }
        }
};

int[][] src = {
        { 77, 88, 99 },
        { 1010, 1111, 1212 }
};

dest[1] = src;  // replace 2D array with id = 1
```

One note, is that in above implementation an array `src` is now refer to the part of an array `dest`, so modification of `src` will be visible in `dest`. To avoid this effect, you have to create a new copy of `src` array and insert it into `dest`:

```
private static void insert(int[][][] dest, int[][] src, int id) {
    int rows = src.length;
    dest[id] = new int[rows][];

    for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++)
        dest[id][row] = Arrays.copyOf(src[row], src[row].length);
}
```